# Concourse not showing up on 8080 when running on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, concourse

I'm setting up a Concourse Docker container by following - https://concoursetutorial.com/ , but on GCP compute Engine.  The tutorial says to access the UI at  http://127.0.0.1:8080/ in your browser.

Since I am running on GCP, i gave :8080, I am getting "This site can’t be reached"

Note- I have enabled the 8080 port in GCP and also in the compute engine.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwRNY.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a firewall that allows 8080 port on GCP and add the network tag of the instance to target.

See detailed instructions here:
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules